# How to connect to parse server backend from back4app.com for Qt android app

Tags: android, qt, parse-platform, back4app, qtandroidextras

I am trying to develop an Android application with `Qt 5.13`. 
I am planning to use a parse-server for my backend. I am using a free plan from [back4app](https://www.back4app.com). I followed the official tutorial [here](https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs/CwBEv0IqdbA9iDYHghz84cWzW4rcWTvzMWmX8JqN?java#installing-parse-sdk)

But I am not sure how to import the android SDK into my Qt C++ code. ?

I added the below code to the `gradle.build` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.20.0"
}

repositories{
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

After this step, I am not sure where to put below code

```
import com.parse.Parse;
```

I need to be able to run the below code in my C++ code.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("appId")
      .clientKey("clientId")
      .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com")
      .build()
```

I tried to import in Qml code without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-android-sdk) you need to put the code into a `.java` file. For that I'd suggest to check the guide on [QAndroidJniObject Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html), as you'll need to do your base implementation in `java` and using java native interface `JNI` to call the code from `C++`.

> Since you'll be needing *https* to access the server. You will also need to include openSSL libs to your project, you can find the required libs and instructions [here](https://github.com/KDAB/android_openssl)

Comment: Thank you.. I will update you once I am able to do this successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this in Java files. So need to learn java. Sorry for delay.  I was working in a different project for a while. Once I finish doing this I will post a link to my code.

Comment: Just make sure not to publish any private keys in your code. For java and Qt KDAB has some nice guides, so might be worth checking them out.